# Starting a windows-application with focus

Tags: winapi, visual-c++

I'm writing a small Windows application in Visual C++ without MVC. Its really small, it just contains one textfield, an OK-Button and an Cancel-Button.

The application is started by a background-process when user starts printing. When opening the application doesn't get focus, isn't even visible.

For the user it's importend that the application is directly in focus, so they have as lease clicks as possible to use it.

I tried many many things to get the application in focus:

```
SetWindowPos(hWnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);
SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
ShowWindow(hWnd, SW_RESTORE);
SetFocus(hWnd);
```

I even repeated this calls in a timer. All of this doesn't work. Now I found some remarks on MSDN:

> The system restricts which processes can set the foreground window. A
>   process can set the foreground window only if one of the following
>   conditions is true:
>
> ```
> The process is the foreground process.
> The process was started by the foreground process.
> The process received the last input event.
> There is no foreground process.
> The foreground process is being debugged.
> The foreground is not locked (see LockSetForegroundWindow).
> The foreground lock time-out has expired (see SPI_GETFOREGROUNDLOCKTIMEOUT in SystemParametersInfo).
> No menus are active.
> ```

Anybody knows a workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.thescarms.com/vbasic/alttab.aspx seems to do the job

```
void forceToFront(HWND hWnd) {
HWND foregroundWindow = GetForegroundWindow();

if (foregroundWindow == hWnd) {
    // Window is already Foreground-window
    return;
}

if (SetForegroundWindow(hWnd)) {
    // could set window to foreground without any tricks
    return;
}

// attach thread of foreground-window to this window
DWORD foregroundThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(foregroundWindow, NULL);
DWORD myThread = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, NULL);
AttachThreadInput(foregroundThread, myThread, true);
SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
AttachThreadInput(foregroundThread, myThread, false);
```

}

Answer (score 4):

There is no workaround for this. The whole point of this new Windows behavior is to prevent applications from bringing themselves to the foreground on their own and being a nuisance. In your case, I would suggest using a notification icon and showing a balloon message when necessary instead of a window. However, even in this case your notification icon can be hidden by the user and there is no workaround, for the same reason as above.

Comment: Quite unsatisfactory. I'll get a real user-acceptance problem if my app doesnt popup directly. Is there any windows option or whatever to prevent this behavior or to permit my application to popup? A last resort would be to simulate a click on task-list, but thats really the last thing I wanne do

Comment: No, there is no such option, otherwise all programs would just set this option on themselves. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/02/26/9445006.aspx and related posts for a discussion of this 'arms race'. You will have to use the notification area or rethink your UI. What's your use case exactly? What are your compatibility requirements?

Comment: One problem with apps that 'interrupt' and pop up is that they can end up inadvertently 'stealing input'. I've had several times in the past where I'm typing away in some text editor, some random popup dialog appears, I hit the space bar as I'm typing, and the dialog then disappears because the space bar ended up triggering some ok or cancel button - all before I even had a chance to read the dialog! Problems like this are exactly why SetForegroundWindow was 'disabled' in this manner - and why notification balloons were introduced instead.

Answer (score 0):

Now, this is coming from a Java developer and not a Visual C++ developer, but can you maybe set the frame/window/whatever-its-called-in-visual-c to be always on top? In Java, if you have  a `JFrame`, say `myJFrame`, you can call `myJFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true)` and it stays on top of all other windows. This seems to be a simple workaround to your problem, however it may not be desirable for the user if it's blocking something of theirs on screen.

Comment: This won't work, because the window is not shown in the first place.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I misunderstood. I thought it was showing up, just beneath all other windows.